# How to Access Azure Storage NFS File Share from another Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account, azure-storage-files

I have a storage account in a subscription which has a VNet that the storage account is setup to use.  This works well in the kubernetes cluster in that subscription that attached to that Vnet. NFS works fine to the the storage account in question.

But we have a secondary subscription for failover in a paired region (East US and West US) that I'd like to have that k8s cluster also be able to mount the NFS share.

I've tried creating a peering and adding the secondary subscription's VNet (which doesn't overlap) to the Storage account, but the k8s cluster in the secondary subscription times out connecting the share.

I didn't do any routing options when creating the peering, but I would have assumed that this would just work.

Does anyone have any instructions on how to get this working so that the secondary cluster can access the NFS share?

Answer (score 0):

The storage sync service and/or storage account can be moved to a different resource group, subscription, or Azure AD tenant. After the storage sync service or storage account is moved, you need to give the `Microsoft.StorageSync` application access to the storage account.

1. Click Access control (IAM) on the left-hand table of contents.
2. Click the Role assignments tab to the list the users and applications (service principals) that have access to your storage account.
3. Verify `Microsoft.StorageSync` or Hybrid File Sync Service (old application name) appears in the list with the Reader and Data Access role.

This [GitHub document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/files/storage-files-faq.md) on Azure file share can give you better insights.

Comment: Microsoft.StorageSync (or any variation that I can find) doesn't exist.

And the agent pool from the k8s in another subscription that couldn't access the NFS share, had Contributor rights.